# Laravel pusher/echo getting broadcast error 500 and 403

Tags: laravel, echo, pusher

Hello I'm trying to make chat system for my app but I'm having problem making pusher and echo work. When I open my Chat between 2 people it does not update in real time and I have to refresh the page in order to get the updated stuff like messages and such. In console I'm getting these 2 errors

**POST http://localhost/broadcasting/auth 403 (Forbidden)**

**POST http://localhost/broadcasting/auth 500 (Internal Server Error)**

bootstrap.js

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
     broadcaster: 'pusher',
     key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
     cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
     encrypted: true,
});
```

ChatBroadcast.php

```
class ChatBroadcast implements ShouldBroadcastNow
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;


    public $ticket;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @param $ticket
     */
    public function __construct(Ticket $ticket)
    {
        $this->ticket = $ticket;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('tickets_channel.' . $this->ticket->id);
    }

    public function broadcastWith(){
        $messages = Message::all()->where('ticket_id','=',$this->ticket->id)->sortBy('created_at');

        return [
            'ticket' => $this->ticket,
            'messages' => $messages
        ];
    }
}
```

channels.php

```
use App\Ticket;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Broadcast;

Broadcast::channel('App.User.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});

Broadcast::channel('tickets_channel.{ticketID}', function ($user, $ticketID) {
    Auth::check();
    $ticket = Ticket::all()->where('id', '=', $ticketID)->first();
    return $ticketID == $ticket->id;
});
```

VueComponent

```
mounted() {
            Echo.private('tickets_channel.${ticketID}')
                .listen('ChatBroadcast', (e) => {
                    console.log(e);
                    this.messagesMutable = e.messages;
                    this.state = e.ticket.isOpened;
                });
        },
```

This is my log for 500 error

```
[2020-09-08 09:25:24] local.ERROR: Invalid channel name private-tickets_channel.${ticketID} {"userId":11,"exception":"[object] (Pusher\\PusherException(code: 0): Invalid channel name private-tickets_channel.${ticketID} at /Users/miroslavjesensky/Documents/Blog/vendor/pusher/pusher-php-server/src/Pusher.php:282)
```

-EDIT-

I have managed to fix the 500 error by changing VueComponent code to this

```
mounted() {
            let id = this.ticket.id;

            Echo.private('tickets_channel' + id)
                .listen('ChatBroadcast', (e) => {
                    this.messagesMutable = e.messages;
                    this.state = e.ticket.isOpened;
                });
        },
```

Comment: i guess because of string, if you are using braces variable, use it like this e.g: "tickets_channel.{$ticketID}"

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was with another VueComponent I am using with the first one. After fixing the listening part of echo there aswell all works as it should